# MEANJS how to send csv to user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I'm using [MEANJS](http://meanjs.org) to do a node app.

Basically I have JSON stored in Mongo that I am using `json-csv`(NPM module) to get out to csv. I was able to get it to download (via a button) locally by doing a couple of tricks. But, when I uploaded it to azure it pooped on me. I rolled back everything and now I don't have the code to post here... but, it didn't really work anyway since I need it to run in azure.

If anyone had some guidance or pointers I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I found that the best way to do this (if the smiles are small) is to use a buffer and and use `res.send()` and make sure to set the `Content-Type`. This gets me around azures issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your csv in azure blob and provide users link to the blob.

BTW, you may still need authentication so a proper solution is providing users a link belonging to your sites and when users click the link, validate auth then redirect to azure blob links.

Comment: This makes more sense, the approach that works locally i save write the file to `public/reports/` I have a feeling that azure is crapping out because it doesn't like the file writing (my guess). I also have this weird freaking issue where my deployments are failing on `"postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"` in my package.json file. Still not sure what that's about yet. I'll try to do the blob storage soon and mark it correct if that worked. Thank you!